# Start.Process not run scipt in separate process

Tags: c#, python, .net-core

I want to run my long runing python script from my console app.
I use 
("my_script.py"), when I shut down console also python script is terminate.
In task manager all(console app and script) is runing under .Net Core Host.
How to run python as completly separated process?

Comment: It could be something that could meet your needs..[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624850/launch-a-completely-independent-process)

Comment: How did you start the process? Post your code. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515360/net-core-process-start-leaving-defunct-child-process-behind) complain that the child process *remains alive* once the parent is killed.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, this would start your python script completely outside of your console application:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\path\to\my_script.py");
```

In classic .NET it will invoke the process via a new shell, but in .NET Core, the process is created directly inside the existing executable.  There is an option to change this, called `UseShellExecute`.  [This is directly from the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> `true` if the shell should be used when starting the process; `false` if the process should be created directly from the executable file. The default is `true` on .NET Framework apps and `false` on .NET Core apps.

This is how you can use it:

```
var myPythonScript = new Process();
myPythonScript.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\to\my_script.py";
myPythonScript.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myPythonScript.Start();
```

When your C# console app terminates, your python script should still be running.

## EDIT

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos, he made me realize the `UseShellExecute` has nothing to do with the parent/child relationship between the processes.  So I setup a sandbox locally with .NET Core and played around with it a bit and this is working for me:

```
var myPythonScript = new Process();
myPythonScript.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\to\python.exe"; // the actual python installation executable on the server
myPythonScript.StartInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\path\to\my_script.py""";
myPythonScript.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myPythonScript.Start();
```

When the parent app terminates, my python script is still running in the background.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something. The question says "Process.Start" (assuming typo) doesn't work. This answer says it does. What am I missing? Is there some subtle interaction in the API or calling sequence that's important?

Comment: @omajid ah, I see now.  I updated my answer.  It's because .NET Core behaves differently than the classic .NET framework

Comment: @jtate It's `directly from the executable file`, which means from the file passed in th epath parameter. There's no attempt to find which application can handle the file extension. Definitely not `directly inside the existing executable`. You can't create a process inside a process.

Comment: `UseShellExecute` is a can of worms. `UseShellExecute` + script will not work on newer versions. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24704. In recent versions it does `xdg-open` instead of `bash -c` :( I would suggest calling out to `bash` manually, but I suspect we will run into OP's question (recursively!)

Comment: @jtate finding the application associated with an extension is the job of the shell. When you set `UseShellExecute` to true you say you want the shell to find out how to execute whatever is passed in the path

Comment: In any case, it's not the *Shell* that controls the parent/child relationship between the processes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're exactly right.  updated my answer with code that actually works :)

Comment: I closed my Process.Start in .net console app, and now I invoke Process.Start(my_console.exe) and it's completely separate process.

Comment: @ianstewart I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but did you get it working?

Comment: Yes it's working now. I tried your solution and in my case it didn't work :(